# Warning message In download.file: download had nonzero exit status

Tags: r, curl, download

I am downloading data from data.gov website and I get following two types of errors in the process:

```
fileUrl <- "http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/expenditures-on-children-by-families"
download.file(fileUrl,destfile=".data/studentdata.csv",method="curl")
Warning message:
In download.file(fileUrl, destfile = ".data/studentdata.csv", method = "curl") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

I tried to remove the method="curl" as suggested in other forum, but again I get this new error

```
download.file(fileUrl,destfile=".data/studentdata.csv")
Error in download.file(fileUrl, destfile = ".data/studentdata.csv") : 
  cannot open destfile '.data/studentdata.csv', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Do you have a directory called `.data` in your current working directory? If not, you need to create that directory or change `destfile` to something else

Comment: does the local .data directory exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two major factors why your `curl` doesn't work well.

**First**, the problem is on your URL. `fileUrl <- "http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/expenditures-on-children-by-families"`. In your URL, it is not referred to a `csv` file. So, they won't work even if you set the destination into a `csv` file such as `destfile = ".data/studentdata.csv"`

I have an example of getting a `csv` dataset using the same code (different dataset):

1. `DataURL<- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"` (This link refers to a rows.csv file)
2. `download.file(DataURL, destfile="./data/rows.csv", method="curl")` (The method is quite same, using `curl`)

**Second**, previously I had the same problem that the `curl` does not work, even I used a proper URL that refers to a `csv` file. However, when I diagnosed a bit deeper, I found something interesting fact about why my `curl` method cannot work properly. It was my R session program. I used a `32-bit` R, in which the error occurs. Later then, I tried to change the session into a `64-bit` R. Amazingly, and the download status was running at that time. To see your R session architecture (whether you are using `32-bit` or `64-bit`), type in your R:

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
>
> Platform: x86_64-w64-ming32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

You have to switch your R, from `32-bit` to `64-bit` to avoid `'curl' call had nonzero exit status`. You go to your R directory folder, and then you run a `64-bit` R.

If you are using a Windows OS and installing the R in a default path folder, you can run this `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\R.exe`. (I used a version of 3.5.3, so it may be different with your version)

If you are using R-studio, you can switch the R session on the menubar `Tools` -> `Global Options` -> `R version` -> `Change` -> `Use your machine's default version of R64 (64-bit)` -> `OK`. Then restart your R-studio.

However, it depends on your OS architecture. If you are using a `32-bit` OS, hence you have to find another way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the code for `download.file(...)`, if you specify `method="curl"` the function tries to use the `curl` shell command. If this command does not exist on your system, you will get the error above.

If you do not specify a method, the default is to use an internal R method to download, which evidently works on your system. In that case, the function is trying to put the file in `.data/studentdata.csv` but evidently there is not `.data` directory. Try taking out the `.`.

When this download works, you will get a `text/html` file, not a csv file. Your url points to a web page, not a download link. That page does have a download link, but unfortunately it is a pdf, not a csv.

Finally, if your goal is to have the data in R (is it?), *and if the link actually produces a csv file*, you could more easily use

```
df <- read.csv(fileUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not very much mistaken you just have a simple typo here. I suspect you have a "data" directory, not a ".data" directory - in which case your only problem is that your destfile string needs to begin "./data", not ".data".

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

Then I realized that I forget to create the "data" directory!

So try adding this above your fileURL line to create the directory first.

```
if(!file.exists("data")){
  dir.create("data")
}
```

Also, if you are running a Mac, then you want to keep method="curl" when downloading a https file. I don't believe Windows has that problem hence the suggestions to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
file<-'http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/expenditures-on-children-by-families'

file<- read.csv(file)